# re-enter the journey after they exit

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I want customers to re-enter the journey after they exit.
This journey is repeated every month.

the questions are:
Will customers wait a month before returning?

What is the best practice for evaluating records in the entry source, evaluating all records or only new ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- After the journey ends, add a wait event that lasts until you want customers to be "blocked" for re-entry (in your case, probably around one month).
- Set the journey settings to "re-entry after exiting"

Those two things will make customer wait a month before returning.

Your second question has no real "general best practice", this is usecase dependent.  It's specifically tied to the question in which mode your data is inserted into the journey data extension (add and update / overwrite), and what the primary key in your data extension is. If you can give those answers, then a recommendation is easier to make.

edited based on comment:

With an (add and) update- automation, and if you have subscriberkey as primary key,there cannot be a "new record" as long as the previous record still exists, your automation would always "update existing records".
Simply because you cannot add the primary key a second time.

Which means: "new records only" will not pick up your record after first insertion.

So, you would have to "evaluate all records", or subscribers already inside the DE will never get picked up more than once.

If your mode were "overwrite", or in case you had a form of data retention in place that cleaned the DE before a new "add and update" query:

This could be  a scenario where the evaluation mode doesn't matter as in both scenarios, there will be no "existing record".
Overwrite purges "existing records" in the DE before insertion, so would a properly configured data retention.

Comment: My contacts are entered with a DE that is updated every day in update with automation studio.  Subcriber Key is my primary key.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: You are sure of this answer ; you would have to "evaluate all records", or subscribers already inside the DE will never get picked up more than once." 
because I have read other answers and they say that to evaluate a customer who entered the Journey several times you have to put New record

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I think that statement is consistent with what I tried to say. "existing users already in the DE do not get picked up" is the same as "in order to make users get picked up, you have to insert them newly", just phrased the opposite way.

Comment: so if i put evaluate "all records", to make a customer who has already entered the Journey re-enter, i have to add it as a new record to the DE?
I understood that it was enough to select evaluate all records

Comment: If subcriberKey (primary key) = 123 it enters the journey. He can only rRe-entry only after exiting
If I put evaluate only new records the subcriberkey 123 will not enter because it is not a new record, even if I have set that it must re-enter after it is exited?

Comment: I can copy someone else's statement, lost the source of the text unfortunately. But here it is explained once more.
Evaluate All Records - This will read the entire DE every single time, so be careful with this if your DE is getting updated instead of overwritten.
You might inject everyone all over again. This is best used along with an Entry Filter that eg. qualify only today's records. This is also a bit slower, so you shouldn't use this if your Journey has very high volumes.

Evaluate New Records Only - This will read only the new rows.

Comment: it regardless if 'Contact Entry' is set to re-enter the journey after they exit?

Comment: Sorry it's getting harder and harder to follow your stream of consciousness. The first two points in my original answer apply. "Evaluate all" does not mean "Inject all". It means "ask the question if the user should be injected", not "answer that question with yes". If you have "evaluate all" but your journey forbids people to be inserted twice ("reentry after exiting"), they might be evaluated but not injected.